# MinGW make not found in NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I am using Windows 10. I want to do c++ code by Netbeans. I have installed "Code-blocks". 
I am able to compile and run c++ code by "codeblocks". Now i want to do it Netbeans. Previously i have done by installing
CygWin. Now i want to do it by MinGW. After opening a c++ project in netbeans when i have press the button run,
a set up dialogh has come. In the base directory selection option i have selected the MinGW bin folder and it has delected all 
commands automatically excepts the make command. Though make command exist there. After explicitly selecting the make command,
it is showing that make command not found.

[image: make command not found in netbeans]

Comment: Your screenshot says "mingw32-make is incompatible and is not supported. Use make from MSYS."

Comment: @melak47 , i have installed MSYS, but finding make

Comment: Should be in MSYS' bin directory. You can also use a different mingw(-w64) distribution that includes it, like https://nuwen.net/mingw.html, or msys2 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40800825/996886 for example).